# Sentinel auth-pass error when using redis 6.0.6

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I don't want to set master redis password in the config file

So I found this command from the redis official website

> sentinel auth-pass <master-group-name> <password>

but when i use the error occurs
like this

127.0.0.1:26378> sentinel auth-pass myMaster 123456
(error) ERR Unknown sentinel subcommand 'auth-user'

why!!!!

Search on Google
and
noting
Maybe I should upgrade to 6.2.0

Comment: getting the same error even on Redis 7.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Sentinel stated supporting auth-user from Redis version 6.2.x. So, it can not find the sub-command `auth-user` which is needed for the command `sentinel auth-pass`.

From Redis Sentinel Official Documentation :

*Starting with Redis 6.2, the Access Control List (ACL) is available, whereas previous versions (starting with Redis 5.0.1) support password-only authentication.*